# Unable to get Web App to work with mysql 5.1 and wildfly 10

Tags: mysql, netbeans-8, wildfly-10

I created a simple mvn webapp in netbeans and got it to work with h2.  But I'm unable to get it to work with mysql as a datasource.

I've deployed the mysql 5.1.38 connector to Wildfly and it deploys and connects fine.  I've added mysql to my persistence.xml as shown below.  But it won't connect.  I can connect to mysql in wildfly, mysql client, and within the services tab in wildfly.

After a lot of effort and research,  I'm kind of lost.

### InitBean

```
package toofar.demo.session;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import toofar.demo.Person;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class InitBean {

    @Inject 
    PersonFacade personFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        personFacade.create(new Person("sad", "Willy"));

        System.err.println(personFacade.find("sad").getName());
    }

}
```

### PersonFacade

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import toofar.demo.Person;


@Stateless
public class PersonFacade extends AbstractFacade<Person> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "toofar_Demo_war_1.0PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public PersonFacade() {
        super(Person.class);
    }

}
```

### AbstractFacade

```
package toofar.demo.session;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

### Entity Person

```
package toofar.demo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    String guid;

    String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String guid, String name) {
        this.guid = guid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

### Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>toofar</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Demo</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

### Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="toofar_Demo_war_1.0PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/toofar</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### Error log and stack trace

```
21:11:07,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Demo-1.0.war#toofar_Demo_war_1.0PU'
21:11:07,302 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:350)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:285)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:626)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:598)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:590)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:563)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:747)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031087: Failed to register DriverClass for: org.mysql.Driver
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:600)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:318)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.Driver from [Module "com.h2database.h2:main" from local module loader @5fcd892a (finder: local module finder @8b87145 (roots: C:\Users\tharper\Downloads\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules,C:\Users\tharper\Downloads\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:591)
    ... 37 more

21:11:07,349 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/toofar
21:11:07,349 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
21:11:07,349 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
21:11:07,350 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Envers integration enabled? : true
21:11:07,364 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:350)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:285)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:626)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:598)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:590)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:563)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:747)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.<init>(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.<init>(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.determineAppropriateJdbcConnectionContext(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.access$100(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$GenerationProcess.execute(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.performGeneration(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031087: Failed to register DriverClass for: org.mysql.Driver
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:600)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:318)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.Driver from [Module "com.h2database.h2:main" from local module loader @5fcd892a (finder: local module finder @8b87145 (roots: C:\Users\tharper\Downloads\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules,C:\Users\tharper\Downloads\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:591)
    ... 29 more

21:11:07,400 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Demo-1.0.war#toofar_Demo_war_1.0PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Demo-1.0.war#toofar_Demo_war_1.0PU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.<init>(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.<init>(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.determineAppropriateJdbcConnectionContext(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.access$100(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$GenerationProcess.execute(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator.performGeneration(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/toofar
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.JpaSchemaGenerator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.<init>(JpaSchemaGenerator.java:629)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/toofar
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:656)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:563)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:747)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:350)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:285)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:626)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:598)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:590)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031087: Failed to register DriverClass for: org.mysql.Driver
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:600)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:318)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.Driver from [Module "com.h2database.h2:main" from local module loader @5fcd892a (finder: local module finder @8b87145 (roots: C:\Users\tharper\Downloads\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules,C:\Users\tharper\Downloads\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDriver(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:591)
    ... 29 more

21:11:07,452 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"Demo-1.0.war#toofar_Demo_war_1.0PU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Demo-1.0.war#toofar_Demo_war_1.0PU\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/toofar
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/toofar
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031087: Failed to register DriverClass for: org.mysql.Driver
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.Driver from [Module \"com.h2database.h2:main\" from local module loader @5fcd892a (finder: local module finder @8b87145 (roots: C:\\Users\\tharper\\Downloads\\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\\modules,C:\\Users\\tharper\\Downloads\\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\\modules\\system\\layers\\base))]"}}
21:11:07,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that wildfly was updating standalone.xml when I would do add a DS and netbeans was looking at standalone-full.xml